# How to correctly specify image links in a content type?

Tags: path-aliases

How to correctly specify img src  like  inside a content like Basic page or Blog, which does not break even when  site is accessed as   http:/example.com/drupalsite or  http://example.com/ and  while accessing as  http:/example.com/node/2 or  http://example.com/path-auto-title ?

Answer (score 1):

First set `$base_url` in your `settings.php` file in *sites/default/* directory.
I am sure you are using [ckeditor](http://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) or some other editor. In editor setting use use [relative URL](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) for images and links. 
Make sure your Apache `mod_rewrite` or `rewrite_module` is enabled.

Comment: i just add <img src="pathtofile/imag.png" />. But this shows image when path generated using path auto is used, while using like node/2, this doesn't generate image

Answer (score 0):

The img src should be saved relative to the domain. But this should be done automatically by Drupal if you upload a file for example with the upload field. How do you place images? Directly in WYSIWYG?

Comment: i just add <img src="pathtofile/imag.png" />. But this shows image when path generated using path auto is used, while using like node/2, this doesn't generate image

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`drupal_get_path_alias`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)

**Parameters**

**$path:** An internal Drupal path.

**$path_language:** An optional language code to look up the path in.

**Return value**

An aliased path if one was found, or the original path if no alias was found.

Comment: But using drupal_get_path_alias is not comfortable for non developers, while editing the contents

Comment: @user7282 +1, but didn't mentioned that you're a non-Developer.

Comment: I am a developer, but once when the site is handed over to customer, a non-developer will be editing the contents

Comment: @user7282, in that case why don't you provide some WYSIWYG editor to the client? You're actually making it difficult to handle for the site admin. If you use WYSIWYG editor there will not be any problem in urls

Comment: Yes, I am using tinymce.But it shows image when url path generated using path auto is used, while using url  like node/2, this doesn't generate image